# Reading package list...Error

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, updates, uninstall

```
Reading package lists... Error!
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type '2oreign' for package 'fonts-tlwg-mono'
E: Problem parsing dependency Depends
E: Error occurred while processing mcp-account-manager-uoa (NewVersion2)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I get this when I try and install apps or update using terminal and software updater.

Content of /etc/apt/source.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20160217.1)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntau
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe
```

Comment: Look into `/etc/apt/sources.list` and fix all crap you wrote there.

Comment: I have never attempted to edit anything in /etc/apt/sources.list? I've never even hear of /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: You probably ran some command that wrote something there, not knowing what it does. Please [edit] your question and post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` there.

Comment: So you added 3 wrong lines at the end by running a command. Remove the last 3 lines.

Comment: Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks OK to me. However, do a `grep -R 2oreign /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, there is something suspicious in another .list file.

Comment: I removed the last three lines (deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe)

then did sudo apt-get update but still received the same error.

I then tried the sudo grep -R 2oreign /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ but nothing happened  and I'm still receiving the same error.